# Renaming files according to the folder they're in

Tags: windows-7, script, rename

I have hundreds of folders named after movies. In each folder there's a `.mkv` file (or `.avi`, `.mp4`), named differently. In each folder there's a `folder.jpg`.

I'd like to rename each video file so that it carries the name of its parent folder. **`folder.jpg` must stay unchanged though.**

For example, the folder structure is like this:

```
 - Movies/Stirb Langsam 1/stlg1.mkv
 - Movies/Stirb Langsam 2/stlg2.mkv
 - Movies/Star Wars 1/hhgdtebds.mkv
 - Movies/Star Wars 2/stwa2.mkv
```

And should be:

```
 - Movies/Stirb Langsam 1/Stirb Langsam 1.mkv
 - Movies/Stirb Langsam 2/Stirb Langsam 2.mkv
 - Movies/Star Wars 1/Star Wars 1.mkv
 - Movies/Star Wars 2/Star Wars 2.mkv
```

At the moment I use Windows 7 for that. Would be nice if one of the scripting gurus could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Save this as a batch file in the root of your tree:

```
@echo off
for /r /d %%x in (*) do (
 pushd "%%x"
 echo %%x
 for /F "delims=" %%i in ("%%x") do (
  ren *.mkv "%%~ni.mkv" 2> NUL
  ren *.avi "%%~ni.avi" 2> NUL
  ren *.mp4 "%%~ni.mp4" 2> NUL
 )
 popd
)
```

Disclaimer: I bear no responsibility for any damage caused.

Though I've tested it on the list you gave, I highly recommend that you back up the files before running the batch file.

Comment: By the way, my script was based on answers to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043869/how-to-execute-a-windows-batch-command-recursively and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432851/dos-bat-file-equivalent-to-unix-basename-command

Comment: Thank you, the script worked for files without a blank and without dot in the name. I found a tool, that helped me out for the rest. <<advanced renamer>>