# Renaming multiple files inside a folder using Windows batch commands

Tags: windows, batch, rename

This is taking the post located [here](https://superuser.com/questions/483726/renaming-files-according-to-the-folder-theyre-in) and spinning things up a bit. 
As typical, I'm trying to rename several images inside a folder to be the name of the folder they're in and then add the suffix "photo1", "photo2" etc.

In other words, I'm trying to go from here:

```
Folder1
  IMG_001.jpg
  IMG_001.jpg
  IMG_003.jpg
```

To here:

```
Folder1
  Folder1_photo1.jpg
  Folder1_photo2.jpg
  Folder1_photo3.jpg
```

Catch is there several hundred of these "Folder" folders, and each one of these will need to have the photos inside of it renamed.

I know there is 3rd party software out there that can do this but I'm looking for a way to run this as a Windows .bat.

If anybody has an idea please share. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming all folders are in the same root folder, and all images match the template IMG_n.jpg, then the following one liner should work on the command line:

```
for /d %A in ("yourRootPath\*") do @for %B in ("%A\img_*.jpg") do @for /f "tokens=1* delims=_0" %C in ("%~nB") do ren "%B" "%~nxA_photo%D.jpg"
```

Don't forget to double up the percents if you use the command in a batch script.

Comment: In the last loop, the delimiter `_0` looks like it should result in `img_001.jpg` becoming `photo01.jpg` but it actually becomes `photo1.jpg`; how does it get rid of the middle 0? It works, but why does it work?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - FOR /F treats any number of consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter. It will split out a token at the first delimiter, and strip out any consecutive delimiters until it reaches the next non-delimiter, where it begins the next token. So "A_B", "A0B", and "A_0_0_0_B" would all yield tokens "A" and "B" if tokens=1* and delims=_0

Comment: I see; delims is a two item list `['_', '0']` instead of a two character string `'_0'` (I should have remembered that). And it works for `img_300.jpg` because `tokens=1*` makes %C = img, %D = the remainder. And the remainder is `300` instead of `300.jpg` because `%~nB` has expanded just the filename without path or extension. Neat!

Answer (score 2):

I see you asked for *Batch*, but others may find PowerShell useful

```
Get-Childitem "C:\my\folder\" -Recurse -Include *.jpg | ForEach {             
    Rename-Item $_ "$($_.Directory.Name)_$($_.Name -ireplace "img_(0+)", "photo").jpg
}
```

Comment: You haven't done the hard bit of renaming the files and numbers from img_00N to photoN. You could use `"$($_.Name -ireplace "img_(0+)", "photo").jpg"` or `"photo$($name.Split('_')[1].TrimStart('0')).jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

How close do you need to get?

This should do it, but it will keep the 0 in the numbers, e.g. `folder1_photo001.jpg` instead of `folder1_photo1.jpg`:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /d %%d in (*) do (

    for %%f in ("%%d/img_*.jpg") do (
        set fname=%%f
        set fname=!fname:IMG_=photo!
        echo ren "%%d/%%f" "%%d/%%d_!fname!"
    )
)
```

(That will print the renaming commands it would run. Remove `echo` to have it actually run them. Have a backup first, verify you're happy with it, there's no undo, etc.).

I can't think of a nice alternative if you do need 1 instead of 001. Replacing the 00 out would risk changing names where there's a number in the name as well, and counting up would break if the numbers aren't contiguous.

[edit: pinched from another answer, I was assuming the pictures are the only things in the folders. Now looks only for `img_*.jpg` pattern].

Answer (score 0):

Look at some software called Irfanview.  It's got a lot of sophisticated bulk rename, resize, conversion, etc. utilities built into it.  I think it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach. I'm not sure if this works, but try it out .

```
cd "path of the folder that contains the photos"

for /L %%n in (1 1 %random%) do (

    for %%f in (*.jpg) do (

        rename "%%f" "photo_%%n.jpg"

    )

)
```